# Feeding events to Flume from C program

Tags: c++, c, thrift, flume, flume-ng

I'm looking for a way to feed events generated by a C program to Apache Flume in an efficient way.

In the C program, events are `struct` instances, which could be serialized to Avro records or such. However, the Avro C library lacks RPC support so the C program cannot connect directly to an Avro Source in the Flume agent.

The current solution is to format events to CSV and feed them to a netcat source in Flume, but text formatting is CPU-hungry (events have lots of numeric fields).

What would be a fast solution for feeding binary data to Flume?

Is there any equivalent of the netcat source in Flume that would allow for binary records?

Maybe a Thrift source in Flume is the solution but previous experience with Apache Thrift showed performance to be a bit underwhelming.

Comment: Thrift is certainly a solution and as you are probably aware, there is a native C implementation available that uses GLib's object framework. If there is a business case for solving this problem I'd be happy to work with you to benchmark the C implementation and, if necessary, improve its performance. (I am one of its authors.)